# Turn on i9300 led even when screen is on

Tags: android, notifications

I'm programming an app to use the galaxy s3 front LED to show notifications. I know, that on the s3 it is possible to turn on the LED even if the screen is on.
My problem is that I don't now how is it made and I can't find any useful documentation about this topic.

I would very appreciate if somebody could provide some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by reverse-engineering some piece of code. There are three files in the directory /sys/devices/virtual/sec/led: led_r, led_g, led_b. By filling the files with the right values (rgb), the phone's notification led will go on, even while screen is on.